# Navigation compose state saving broke after updating to a new library version

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

One day I needed a Google Accompanist library implemented to my Jetpack Compose project. As the library depends on the current stable Compose version, I had to update it along with `navigation-compose` library. Things broke.

I use `BottomNavigation` as the top-level navigation and navigate deeper from within the tabs tied to this `BottomNavigation`. Each tab has its own `NavHostController`, that I want to save into a `Bundle` to restore the controller later. Use-case:

1. User opens Tab 1
2. Navigates to another screen from inside Tab 1
3. Switches to Tab 2
4. Switches back to Tab 1. The screen opened on step 2 is the current destination of Tab 1's `NavGraph`

The code provided in the Before state works as intended.

### Before

My dependencies before the migration(compose version 1.0.0-alpha12):

```
    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
```

In my top-level composable, where the `BottomNavigation` is called, I have a state:

```
    val employeesNavState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(Bundle()) }
```

Which I pass to my Tab composable:

```
EmployeesTab(employeesNavState)
```

That is described by the following function:

```
@Composable
fun EmployeesTab(navState: MutableState<Bundle>) {
    val navController = rememberNavController() // The navController responsible for navigation state
    DisposableEffect(null) {
        val callback = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
            // The state is saved on each navigation event
            navState.value = controller.saveState() ?: Bundle()
        }
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(callback)
        // The state is restored from the navState created by the callback
        navController.restoreState(navState.value)

        onDispose {
            navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(callback)
            // workaround for issue where back press is intercepted
            // outside this tab, even after this Composable is disposed
            navController.enableOnBackPressed(false)
        }
    }

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "employees") {
        composable("employees") {
            appBarViewModel.onNavigate(AppScreen.Employees, navController)
            Employees(it.hiltViewModel(), navController)
        }
        composable("employee/{userId}") {
            appBarViewModel.onNavigate(AppScreen.EmployeeDetails, navController)
            Employee(it.hiltViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

### After

My dependencies after the migration(compose version 1.0.3):

```
    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.19.0"
```

And every single bit of the other code stays the same. Somehow, this just stopped working. I did some debugging and made sure `controller.saveState()` does not return `null`. Callback is fired in both versions.

The only thing that I found to be different is `navigate()` function of the `NavController`, that is an extension function in `navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha07` and a member function in `navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10`. I call it from inside the `Employees` composable.

### The question

What changed inside the API that it stopped working without throwing any error? How do I mutate my code to replicate the "Before" behavior?

Comment: Why are you using multiple NavHosts at all? You don't need any of that to save the state of each tab - that's what the `saveState` and `restoreState` flags in the [bottom nav integration example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) do for you.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I inherited this project from another developer, and this is how he implemented this behavior. I will follow the example in a provided link and post an update. Thank you